# Beta testing stage for android app, clean install?

Tags: android, database, installation, beta-testing

In general, is it a bad idea to require beta testers to do a clean install of the app with every update? The reason I ask is because I prefer not writing the code to upgrade the internal sqlite databases and save time on other tasks. Is there a way to require a clean install with a new version number (version code hasn't incremented yet)?

Comment: If you don't cater for database upgrades then do you expect your users to perform a clean install?

Comment: As for beta testing not writing the code to upgrade will indeed save you time. I think you can skip it until your last tests, where you need to be sure it works correctly.

Comment: IMHO, it is not a beta test if your code is not feature complete, which would include handling database upgrades. Also, your testers either will not use the app in a realistic fashion (because they do not want to waste time entering data that they will lose) or will be pissed at you (because they *did* waste that time).

Comment: @CommonsWare that's intended that they reenter data because changes have been made to how the data is saved.

Comment: also, most of the data is stored on an external server and is reloaded into the database without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not a big deal to handle upgrades.  I create a string that does describes the change:

```
private static final String ALTER_TABLE1 = 
        "ALTER TABLE player ADD COLUMN enablesound INTEGER DEFAULT 1";
```

and when your database version changes for your users, you execute this helper function:

```
 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ". No data will be destroyed");
      if (oldVersion == 1) {
            db.execSQL(ALTER_TABLE1);
      }
  }
```